# Joining tables with codeigniter active record

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to update my code from query to codeigniter active records.

This here is my old code

```
public function get_categories($parent_id = 0) {

    $language_id = "1";

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "category c LEFT JOIN " . $this->db->dbprefix . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) LEFT JOIN " . $this->db->dbprefix . "category_to_store c2s ON (c.category_id = c2s.category_id) WHERE c.parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "' AND c2s.store_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "'  AND c.status = '1' ORDER BY c.sort_order, LCASE(cd.name)");

    return $query->result_array();
}
```

And i am trying to update it to new code below

The problem I am having is it not getting the correct result by the id. And since upgrading to CI-3 old code does not work.

```
public function get_categories($parent_id = 0) {
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('category');
    $this->db->join('category_description', 'category_description.category_id = category.category_id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
```

**How can I use the codeigniter join properly. to be able to get my code to work.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after upgrading to Codeigniter 3.0 you need to update your database config file:

delete: `$active_record = TRUE;`

add: `$query_builder = TRUE;`

there is actually more to consider updating, the full documentation you find here:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html

and

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrade_300.html